# How to reduce Magento 2 rest api performance time?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, rest-api, webapi

I have created some custom rest api's and using Magento's default rest api's.

I want to reduce the loading time of the api, as I have custom api's too so the request time and response time is quite more than usual.

Is there any way or solution to this scenario. that will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kindly follow these steps while developing:

- do not use addAttributeToSelect(*), only select attributes which you need.
- do not use ObjectManager
- Use the Magento\Framework\Data\Collection class to retrieve a collection of filtered objects instead of directly querying the database.
- Avoid creating helper classes
- use caching practice in GET API calls
- to boost your APIs you can use the following module: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_APIEnhancer